# How to define a generic function which takes generic class names in Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following method:

```
public static WebElement getElement(String element, WebDriver driver){

    Class<LoginPage> types=LoginPage.class;     
    java.lang.reflect.Field field=types.getDeclaredField(element);   
    field.setAccessible(true);   
    WebElement webelement=(WebElement)field.get(element); 
    return webElement;
}
```

Here were are using a LoginPage class.
The getDeclaredField and field.get(element) methods will return me the
fields defined in the LoginPage.class.
How can we define a generic Class method, which can take any type of ClassName?

Comment: Just add a parameter `Class<?> types` to the method. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: How does it work? you meant Class<Types> types=Types.class;

Comment: If you're going to this much trouble, might want to take a look at Geb. The Page Object model would probably do all this for you and a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the `Class` variable a method parameter:

```
public static WebElement getElement(String element, WebDriver driver, Class<?> clazz){
    java.lang.reflect.Field field=clazz.getDeclaredField(element);   
    field.setAccessible(true);   
    WebElement webelement=(WebElement)field.get(element); 
    return webElement;
}
```

Sample call:

```
WebElement e = getElement("elementName", driver, LoginPage.class);
```

Comment: in the Sample call, is it possible to get the class name directly? actually there are several classes, so each time I have to provide the class name to make a call

Comment: @user3640657 I'm not sure what you mean by getting the class name "directly".

Comment: for example :WebElement e=getElement("elementName",driver,<Parameter>.class)

Comment: @user3640657 That's not valid syntax, and I don't know what you're trying demonstrate.

Comment: Sample call:

WebElement e = getElement("elementName", driver, LoginPage.class); , As per this, we can pass only LoginPage.class. If i have 100 classes, i have to touch the code everytime, so how can i do the parameterization

Comment: @user3640657 Who said you can only pass `LoginPage.class`? You can pass any class you like.

Comment: i know i can pass any class, but i have to define it everytime right like:WebElement e = getElement("elementName", driver, LoginPage.class);WebElement e = getElement("elementName", driver, x.class);WebElement e = getElement("elementName", driver, y.class); like that.. i  want to define it only one time

Comment: @user3640657 No you don't. Methods can accept dynamic arguments. Let me ask you, how would you envision an ideal solution?